# User's last login with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to record the last login info of a user into the database. So I'm thinking to put something like the code below in all of my controllers' action methods.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    // save DateTime.Now for this user
}
```

However, I have a moderately huge number of controller actions. And this approach will also be difficult to manage in the long run. Is there a simpler and best way to do this?

Thanks.

[edit]
With Forms Authentication, when the logon form's "remember me" is checked, the next time the user comes back they don't go to the login page anymore. That's the reason I came up with the idea above. But I really don't like it and I will appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean "last login" or "last access"? If the former, just set it when the user successfully logs in. If the latter, you can create an `HttpModule` that inspects incoming requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [`MembershipUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1b506ez.aspx) type (which you are likely using) *has* a [`LastLoginDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastlogindate.aspx) and a [`LastActivityDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastactivitydate.aspx) property. You should use those if possible.

If not, you can handle both "last login" and "last access" with an `HttpModule`:

```
public class LastTimeModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // This event is raised prior to *any* handler request ("last access")
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(OnPreRequest);

        // This event is raised when a user is authenticated ("last login")
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(OnPostAuthenticateRequest); 
    }

    void OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Log time here
    }

    public void OnPreRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Log time here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC you could create a custom action filter and apply it to your controllers.